# How do I create a RESTful API using Python?

Tags: python, api, rest

I need to create an API for the web app of our startup. The backend is in PHP/MySQL. I wanted to first make a python API before I make APIs in other languages. I know there is the Django REST framework that can be used to create API. What I want to know is:

1. Is it ok to make an API in python first for the PHP-backend web app or is that independent
2. Do i need to create a separate database to store API requests or do i use existing to GET/POST API calls?
3. How do I implement the Authentication keys and secret for API authentication?

Comment: Have you read [this blog entry](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask) on designing a RESTful API using Python and Flask?  Excellent tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

This question may not be best for StackOverflow, but I'll answer it because I had the same question for a long time before someone helped me out.

I HIGHLY recommend [Flask-RESTful](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It is incredible for making lightweight, fast, and efficient APIs. In fact, I think micro-frameworks like Flask are the best for APIs in general.

It works with MySQL. You say that your back-end is in PHP, but why would you want to use PHP and then make a Python API? Beats me, but it's your app. They make it really easy to make endpoints for the API, and there are tons of step-by-step guides out there. Check out [this one](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-using-flask-restful). Helped me out a lot when I was starting out.

Comment: i am implementing an API for the first time....i see websites make APIs in different languages regardless of their backend....why do u think it does not make sense to first start with a python API even though backend is in PHP??

Comment: Usually you will have some common logic between backend and APi that you can make reusable. And besides that you won't have many moving parts written in multiple languages. But why Python specifically for API? PHP is not so bad for the same as well. Any particular reason for choosing Python?

Comment: i just thought it would be easier to start with bcuz i am more comfortable in python.

Comment: can someone correct me on this: i will use my existing database to GET/POST info from an API request right? i do not need to create a separate database for the REST API service, right?

Comment: That's the real point of having an API. It allows you to interact with your database externally and (hopefully) safely. So, you wouldn't need extra databases, but it's probably a good idea to have copies of your database for development and testing

Comment: hey Alex, thanks for the reply. I have been reading more about designing APIs...since my backend is in PHP, my restful API should be in PHP too? if yes, how can i then provide users who will use our API different client libraries. Example Stripe who provide client libraries in PHP, Python, Ruby etc. Thanks again for the reply :)

Comment: Having just a straight up RESTful API and providing client APIs are different beasts. A RESTful API can be connected with any language. Do you want to do both things?

Comment: yes i want to do both things. so i am assuming my first priority is to implement the RESTful API (which will be in PHP since the backend of our eCommerce website is in PHP) and once i have that working, i then have to provide the client APIs right?

Comment: yeah, definitely do the REST API first. It's more important typically than the client API. After that then implement each client API in order of most popular language I would say

Comment: Alex, you have been very helpful....i had mixed up the terminologies when i asked my question here but u helped me clarify all this....than k u so much....really appreciate it :)

Comment: hey alex, i already asked this but just out of curiosity....what would be the biggest disadvantage of writing a REST API using python (and its respective framework) for a backend that is in PHP? its just a general question out of curiosity

Comment: just added work, really

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54232/discussion-between-ueg1990-and-alex-chumbley).